# Why git says "nothing to commit"

Tags: git

Not sure why Git stopped working?

```
$ git branch 

beta
* staging
```

I make some changes to code.

```
git add --all
git commit -m "changed some stuff"

# On branch staging
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Comment: What does `git status` tell you? Did you perhaps change some files that are ignored?

Comment: Not an ignored file. git status says the same "nothing to commit"

Comment: Then you must have already committed your changes locally. You might want to run `git push` now.

Comment: Check out [git - the simple guide](http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/)

Comment: check if `git diff HEAD~` give you your latest changes

Comment: @jdog information provided is not sufficient. Can you please attach snapshots and logs.

Comment: add result of :  "git remote -v"

Comment: do a simple modification in one of the files and add result of  "git status" (before doing git add ; git commit)

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to share-folder on OSX. Resolved by sharing the folder.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. What is the output of `git status` on your machine?